# Can you control the speed of a DC motor with a stepper motor controller?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-driver

I want to make an RC car and for that I need to control speed. Can I use a stepper motor controller to do this?

Comment: There are modules that can control either, with suitable programming (either writing a register, or moving a jumper). If your stepper controller is such a module, then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: (Containing a bunch of half- or full bridges, most stepper motor *driver*s couldn't care less whether connected to a solenoid, brushed motor, relay, incandescent lamp, …. Being "switches" or current sources, they may be a nuisance to control as a voltage/speed control.)

Comment: (You need something else completely if the motor to control was electronically commutated/BLDC.)

Answer (score 4):

No, that won't work.

A stepper motor driver outputs switched DC waveforms, which is somewhat similar to AC, in sync with the position of the shaft.

A DC motor requires DC. A PWM is also a switched DC waveform, but at a much higher frequency, so the motor doesn't mind.

Answer (score 2):

A **stepper motor** has multiple windings which are switched in a repeated sequence to rotate the motor armature and shaft (see below [picture/diagram](https://digilent.com/blog/how-to-use-a-stepper-motor/)). So the driver has a series of drive outputs that are each on or off. The speed of the motor is controlled by the speed of the sequence.

A **brushed DC motor** uses a single DC supply. Its speed is controlled by varying the DC voltage supplied to the motor. That can be done with an adjustable steady drive voltage or by switching a constant drive voltage using PWM.

So if you have a stepper motor speed controller, you can't use it for speed control of a brushed DC motor.

If you have a stepper motor driver circuit connected to (e.g.) a microcontroller that you can write software for and program yourself, then you may be able to use a single winding driver output and switch it with PWM to control the motor speed. The driver circuit must be capable of supplying the motor stall current and switching at the PWM frequency. 2 kHz is a good and typical value for small DC motors in RC-type equipment.

A **brushless DC motor** is much more complicated to control and certainly can't use your stepper motor controller. But I doubt that's what you have.

---

Just for info...

I imagine you have a brushed DC motor. PWM control has substantial benefits over varying the voltage linearly. If the PWM frequency is high enough then the DC motor will act as a voltage averaging device and the speed can be controlled by varying the PWM waveform's mark-space ratio. Done properly, little of the power is wasted as heat in the drive circuitry, so nearly all of the consumed power is delivered to the motor.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As greybeard comments

> Containing a bunch of half- or full bridges, most stepper motor drivers couldn't care less whether connected to a solenoid, brushed motor, relay, incandescent lamp, …. Being "switches" or current sources, they may be a nuisance to control as a voltage/speed control.

so you can do this about as well as you can drive a screw with a hammer.  with enough effort you can get something that barely works.

If this is the traction motor for your RC car then I would not recommend trying that approach.

Get an electronic torque control and control it using PWM .

Comment: yeah, that would work about as well as driving a stepper motor from a PWM source.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be possible to rectify the PWM outputs of a stepper motor controller to get a variable DC drive voltage. I haven't done much with stepper motors, and this idea may depend on just how the drive is implemented (perhaps using [microstepping](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/238230/microstepping-methods-for-stepper-motors-pwm-phase-frequency)).

But I was thinking more about a BLDC or AC induction motor VFD, where the three phase outputs could be rectified to drive a brushed DC motor.